# Setting north arrow angle in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

[image]
If you select in QGIS:  View, Decorations, North arrow, then a window pops up with some parameters regarding the north arrow. One of these parameters is Angle. If you select automatic, then the angle is shown in degrees. Obviously this value is the angle in degrees (in my example 170) between the north position that is currently on the screen and the true north position.

Is it possible to retrieve or to calculate this value (like the north arrow function does)?

I work with WGS84 /EPSG:3031. I have an excel file with ship position data including heading information that I can load into QGIS. It works, every position is marked with a point. But instead of a point I would like to see a little arrow which shows the ship's heading. But this works only when I know this degree value. I could then add the ship's heading information and the arrow would be displayed correctly (with the help of Layer properties, single symbol up-arrow, rotation parameter). In my example the red arrows (the ship's course) are labeled with the timestamp and the heading information from the file.

Comment: what kind of "heading information" does the dataset include? with @map_rotation you can get your current map rotation in the expression editor. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: No. The heading information is in degrees (0-359). Assume the north arrow points straight downwards on the display, so the angle in the north arrow window displays 180. Assume the heading information in the file is 270. That means the ship goes straight westwards and the little arrow (svg up-arrow) that marks the ship's position must point straight rightwards. So the task is to calculate the north direction angle (180) and then add the heading information from the file (270). 180+270=450. 450-360=90 --> straight rightwards on the display.

Comment: if you use your heading information for the rotation of the arrow, QGIS should automaticly correct for the rotation of your project. You can rotate your project with the rotation field in the botom bar between magnifier and render.

Comment: Thanks for your message, nepluisse. I have uploaded a QGIS screenshot. The red arrows are labeled with the time stamp and the heading of the ship. This is what I like to get. No rotation of the project. All I need is the value of the angle in the north arrow function. Do you know how this is calculated?